# Snowflake is not able to download file from S3 without access key, while s3fs is able to download that file from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, python-s3fs

I have a S3 URL to a public file similar to the following URL example: **s3://test-public/new/solution/file.csv**   (this is not the actual link . just a close example to the one i'm using)

I am able to read the file using **s3fs** module in a python script, **without** placing any AWS key ID, nor AWS Secret Key,  as follows:

```
with fs.open('test-public/new/solution/file.csv'):
```

however, when i try to read the same file from S3 to Snowflake stage or from ***Table*** -> ***Load table***, Snowlake reports that AWS key ID, and AWS Secret Key are missing, though these fields are optional

[image]

Is there a way i can read a public file from S3 into a snowflake table without any AWS credentials (as with s3fs) ?

Comment: You could probably give it a garbage key/secret, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @parsifal  i already tried, it doesnt work

Comment: Did you try creating a stage without those parameters and then reference the stage in your COPY statement?  It would be helpful if you'd include your COPY command details in your posting.

Comment: [STORAGE_INTEGRATION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#external-stage-parameters-externalstageparams) = integration_name or CREDENTIALS = ( cloud_specific_credentials ) are required only if the storage location is private/protected; not required for public buckets/containers, so in your case you can skip them if you have a public bucket.

Answer (score 1):

`STORAGE_INTEGRATION` or `CREDENTIALS` are required only if the storage location is private not required for public buckets.

Make sure you have defined the bucket policy appropriately.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy16361",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Pub Bucket Policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::pubucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::pubucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you have the above policy defined for an S3 bucket, you can either create the stage or load directly into a table:

```
--create stage, list files, view file content
create or replace stage my_s3_stage url='s3://pubucket/test.csv';
ls @my_s3_stage;
select $1 from @my_s3_stage;

--or even load directly from file
create or replace table mytable (cola varchar);
copy into mytable from 's3://pubucket/test.csv';
select * from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach works to import data from S3 into a snowgflake Table:

```
COPY INTO SNOW_SCHEMA.table_name  FROM  's3://test-public/new/solution/file.csv'
```